# Need help with 7z command

Tags: 7z, hfs+, p7zip

I have a file called `BaseSystem.dmg` which contains a hfs+ system image as well as other files. I am trying to extract just the hfs+ system image file using `7z` from the `p7zip-full` package.

I have tried all these commands and others too...

```
7z x BaseSystem.dmg
7z e BaseSystem.dmg
7z x BaseSystem.dmg 4.hfs
```

Instead of extracting just the 4.hfs file I either get nothing or 7z goes straight to extracting all files and folders in BaseSystem.dmg.

I am able to use `dmg2img` like this and it works...

```
dmg2img -p 4 -i BaseSystem.dmg -o 4.hfs
```

But my question is about how do I use the `7z command` to extract just the 4.hfs file from BaseSystem.dmg?

Cheers

### Update

I get the same result when I use 7-Zip 19.00 (32 bit or 64 bit) on Windows and also when I use 16.02 (64 bit) on Ubuntu.

I know that this is possible because [Boot Disk Utility](http://cvad-mac.narod.ru/index/bootdiskutility_exe/0-5) uses 7-Zip 19.00 (32 ) and IS able to extract 4.hfs from BaseSystem.dmg. However I don't know what parameters it uses. I actually also downloaded 7-Zip 19.00 (32 ) separately for my Windows OS and again when I run it myself it does not extract just the 4.hfs file.

So it must be something about what 7z parameters I am using?

Comment: Have you read https://superuser.com/questions/321829/extract-a-certain-file-from-an-archive-with-7-zip-from-the-command-line/322233 (seems like you're already doing that, but if it doesn't work, it doesn't work, and you simply can't use your version of 7z; what version is that, by the way?)? (also, there's nothing OS-specific in here, not quite sure this should be here instead of superuser.com)

Comment: I updated my question with some more info as you request. I posted my question [on SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/1652034/7z-command-does-not-extract-individual-partition-from-dmg-file) also.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to this by asking the [7-Zip author at SourceForge](https://sourceforge.net/p/sevenzip/discussion/45797/thread/5b84059337/#5b60).

In my case this is the command I needed to extract *just* the 4.hfs partition from BaseSystem.dmg:

```
7z e -t* BaseSystem.dmg 4.hfs
```

This command lists the files one level deep in BaseSystem.dmg:

```
7z l -t* BaseSystem.dmg
```